# Set a secure https connection for Oauth2 on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I'm trying to use the google people API to automate some contact creating on our Work Phones. But for using people API, I need to use OAuth 2, and I'm using the following code. I go to the authorization URL, get authorization response, but when I run the token line I get the error:

```
InsecureTransportError: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.
```

The code is as follows:

```
import json
with open(r'C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\client_id.json') as abb:
    ab = json.load(abb)



client_id = ab['installed']['client_id']
redirect_uri = ab['installed']['redirect_uris'][0]
client_secret = ab['installed']['client_secret']

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session


scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']
oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                          scope=scope)
authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        # access_type and prompt are Google specific extra
        # parameters.
        access_type="offline", prompt="select_account")

#authorization_response = input('Enter the full callback URL')
authorization_response = r'RESPONSE'


token = oauth.fetch_token(
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        authorization_response=authorization_response,
        # Google specific extra parameter used for client
        # authentication
        client_secret=client_secret,
        )
```

I think I all need to do is set up an https server? But I tried to find examples of OAuth2 servers, and all I got was people telling to disable the requirement for testing. I do not want to test, I want to run the OAuth so I can call requests on people API.

Answer (score 6):

Try to shoot `export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=1`in the terminal. It should work.